# Would Voldemort have succeeded if he simply ignored the prophecy?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

It seems that the only reason Voldemort needed to kill Harry Potter was the prophecy. Harry himself didn't possess any special powers and was only spared from death thanks to the sacrifice of his mother.

So what would've happened if Voldemort had simply ignored it? Would he have won the Wizarding War once and for all?

Comment: To the close voters: not opinion based; as the top voted answer shows, this is perfectly answerable from canon.

Comment: @SQB Disagree - the only thing the answers support is that he wouldn't have been disembodied and eventually beaten **by Harry**. Whether or not he would have **actually succeeded** in defeating the Ministry and the Order is complete speculation.

Comment: i believe there is a dumbledore quote somewhere (maybe the supplemental tales of the beetle and the bard book?) that discusses Villians causing their own downfall through fear of an uprising.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### **It's the old debate of choice vs destiny**

That is, [free will vs determinism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incompatibilism-arguments/) all over again. JKR's stance is pretty clear on it:

> " Destiny is a name often given in retrospect to choices that had
> dramatic consequences."

And again from Dumbledore's mouth:

> "It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than
> our abilities" *~Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

So, our choices matter, they have consequences. Voldemorts choices happened to bring his own downfall, he is the one responsible, not some foggy prophecy. He pushed Lily beyond her limits, and she made  her ultimate sacrifice,  creating Voldemort's enemy.

After all, if you choose to kill people chances are that they'll try to kill you back and eventually succeed (live by the sword, die by the sword, what goes around comes around,  etc.)

### **Would Voldemort have lived forever and ever undefeated if he'd ignored the prophecy?**

Of course not. Had he decided to leave the Potters alone, he wouldn't have made Harry his equal and his mortal enemy, but being a dark lord is a dangerous profession. Sooner or later he'd have pushed someone else hard enough and they'd have pushed back just as hard.

Voldemort's *choices*, that's what determined his fate. The names of the heroes aren't that important :  Harry, Neville (whom Rowling called 'might-have-been') or another kid... Sooner or later Voldemort would have created a foe strong enough to bring him down.

Answer (score 47):

## The prophecy would have been meaningless if he had ignored it.

## Ignoring *The Cursed Child*

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Dumbledore says:

> "If Voldemort had never heard of the prophecy, **would it have been fulfilled? Would it have meant anything? Of course not!** Do you think that every prophecy in the Hall of Prophecy has been fulfilled?"
> "But," said Harry, bewildered, "but last year, you said one of us would have to kill the other -"
> "Harry, Harry, only because Voldemort made a grave error, and acted on Professor Trelawney's words! If Voldemort had never murdered your father, would he have imparted in you a furious desire for revenge? Of course not! If he had not forced your mother to die for you, would he have given you a magical protection he could not penetrate? Of course not, Harry! Don't you see? **Voldemort himself created his worst enemy, just as tyrants everywhere do!** Have you any idea how much tyrants fear the people they oppress? All of them realize that, one day, amongst their many victims, there is sure to be one who rises against them and strikes back! Voldemort is no different! (etc)

So in relying too much on the prophecy, he handed Harry some powerful tools, and *made him the one would defeat him*.

So it seems that if Voldemort had never heard the prophecy, he would have survived that night.

## With *The Cursed Child*

> Delphi's last plan to save her father was to just prevent him from heading to the Potters that night. She was under the impression that that would save him.

So it seems as if

> If he hadn't gone, he wouldn't have 'died' that night, and would probably have never been defeated.

Comment: What is "TCC"? I'm sure that is common knowledge for fans but I don't know it. Also why it is important to specify with and without TCC?

Comment: The Cursed Child (the new theater piece).

Comment: @Erik Because The Cursed Child (TCC), the new play, was fairly awful. TBH, I only read the screenplay, not actually watched it, but that was just... Yeech. So some fans are now not counting TCC as canon (even though, unfortunately, it is).

Comment: With the logic provided in this answer (which I agree with and approve of), would this [prophecy] befit the figure of speech "self-fulfilling prophecy"? //***edit***: ignoring TCC of course

Comment: @Mithrandir Thank you for that clarification. It all makes good sense now.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Yes, absolutely. That's actually a major theme of divination in Harry Potter. Everything Trelawny teaches is total bunk, and both of the "real" prophecies that she speaks are self-fulfilling.

Comment: @Mithrandir Having seen the play, and read the rehearsal-version script (screenplay seems the wrong word here, given the absence of a screen), all I can say is that one is a poor shadow of the other. It was written as a play, for the West End, and works extremely well in that context. I feel deeply sorry for anyone who read the script first.

Comment: @ssmart I went and watched the play myself not too long ago, and the effects are amazing and the casting (for the most part) is pretty spot on. It doesn't redeem the story, though...

Comment: @CoreDumpError how is the second prophecy self-fullfilling? What did Harry/Dumbledore do so that it came true?

Comment: @Ruslan Had Harry not heard the prophecy, the chain of events that led to Pettigrew being discovered would not have occurred. He only left Ron's side and fled to Voldemort because he'd been outed. He would have happily kept being the Wesley's Pet Rat if given the opportunity.

Answer (score 5):

**Some Time-Travel Theory**

There are roughly two ways in which prophecy and time-travel can work:

1. [Novikov's self-consistency principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle): There is only one self-consistent timeline, and anything you do in the past (or as a result of prophecy), was already part of the timeline in the first place. You cannot *change* the past, but you can *affect* it. In particular, you can retroactively be the *cause* of events you already know happened (creating a 'causal loop').
2. [The Many Worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation): Any change you make in the past splits the timeline into two branches; one in which you made the change, and one in which you didn't. In this theory, you can travel back in time and cause events that are inconsistent with your native timeline.

**The Main Books**

The main series of Harry Potter books follow *Novikov's principle*. The time-turner events in Prisoner of Azkaban are an excellent example of this. Everything the heroes see and hear their first time around is consistent with their actions and observations in the second iteration. In particular, future-Harry creates a causal loop by saving past-Harry's life.

The prophecy also fits this theory. Voldemort acts on it, unknowingly allowing it to come to pass: another causal loop. He did have some choice in *how* to fulfill the prophecy, because until he marked Harry as his equal, Neville fit the description too.

But **Voldemort could not have ignored the prophecy**. Don't misunderstand: the prophecy didn't magically compel him or anything. He still acted on it by his own free will. But in any universe in which Voldemort had it in him to ignore such a prophecy, the prophecy would not have been made in the first place.

[**The Cursed Child**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child)

If this recent screenplay is to be considered canon, that throws Novikov's self-consistency principle out the window. It comes closer to the Many Worlds theory, but it violates some of *its* rules, too. Sloppy writing, in other words, and what a shame after such a well-crafted series.

In this expanded canon, the closest answer to your question is **yes**. But really, because it doesn't adhere to any consistent set of time-travel rules, the answer probably depends on what would make for the best story.

Comment: +1, though PoA isnt as unequivocal on time travel as you describe. Acc to Novikov's principle you cannot create time paradoxes, but H says: "Professor McGonagall told me what awful things have happened when wizards have meddled with time. . . . Loads of them ended up killing their past or future selves by mistake!”~POA

Comment: @R.Skeeter: Ah, I didn't remember that line. Indeed, killing your future self is possible, but killing your past self is not. I suppose we could explain this away by saying Hermione was wrong about what McGonagall said, McGonagall was wrong about what she thought she knew, or it is just a badly thought-out cautionary tale told to students in the wizarding world.

Answer (score 2):

Yes he would have been more successful as it was the prophecy that lead him to the Potters ( why not Longbottoms)  and forced him to cast the deathly spell on the little Harry... If there would have been a case where he would not listen to the prophecy he would have been alive!
But it is a scenario where it shows that even when people are at the top of their game there is a slight fear in them and this slight fear leads to bad decisions as in this case made by Voldemort!
Kudos!